# Concatenation of two uint8_t pointer

Tags: c, concatenation, uint8t

I am using two uint8_t pointers

```
uint8_t *A_string = "hello"
uint8_t *B_string = "world"
```

And I am trying to concatenate both these using strcat

```
strcat(A_string, B_string);
```

I am getting an error saying "uint8_t is incompatible with parameter of type char* *restrict*"

So I type casted both A_string and B_string to char* and tried . Now I am not getting the error but the concatenation is not happening .

Can anyone please let me know how do I convatenate two strings which are of type uint8_t *  ?

Comment: Is this C++ or C? These are two different languages with different approaches.

Comment: Compiler is likely not appending the terminating null character since it cannot convert this to a c-style string.

Comment: I’ve deleted the [tag:c++] tag since C ≠ C++ and the code you’ve posted is not valid C++.

Comment: Can you include the code where you tried to concatenate them?

Comment: It is in a C program

Comment: @tadman It *is* a standard type. Using `char` here wouldn’t fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A_string` points to an unmodifiable [*string literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). However, the first argument of [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) mustn’t be a pointer to a string literal — it must be a pointer to a *modifiable array*, and furthermore the array must be large enough to hold the result of the concatenation.

To fix the issue, declare `A_string` as an array of sufficient size.

Furthermore, heed the compiler warnings: you have a potential signedness mismatch in your code that might cause problems. In fact, you probably want to use `char` instead of `uint8_t` here.

Here’s a fixed version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // 11 = strlen("hello") + strlen("world") + 1
    char a_string[11] = "hello";
    char const *b_string = "world";
    strcat(a_string, b_string);

    printf("%s\n", a_string);
}
```

In reality you usually wouldn’t hard-code the array size since if you knew it you could just as well concatenate the string literals yourself in the source code.

Instead you’d need to *calculate* the requires size, and dynamically allocate a buffer of sufficient size using `malloc`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char const *a_string = "hello";
    char const *b_string = "world";
    
    size_t total_len = strlen(a_string) + strlen(b_string) + 1;
    char *result = malloc(total_len);
    if (! result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate array of size %zu\n", total_len);
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(result, a_string);
    strcat(result, b_string);

    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the points , it works for me now.